# Get JSON object attribute

Tags: json

I am trying to read a JSON object within an object;

```
{"messageID":15920401,"command":{"ageMinutes":0,"commandText":"test_command"}}
```

Using this code I can read the command contents, and messageID. However I can't read any of the attributes within the command object without getting exceptions that they can't be found;

```
    public void checkForCommands(String message){

    JSONObject obj;
    JSONObject obj2;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(message);
        JSONObject array = obj.getJSONObject("command");
        int id = obj.getInt("messageId");
        log.debug(array);
        log.debug(id);

        obj2 = new JSONObject(array);

        int age = obj2.getInt("ageMinutes");
        String commandText = obj2.getString("commandText");

        log.debug(age);
        log.debug(commandText);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The log for array gives: {"ageMinutes":0,"commandText":"test_command"}

The log for id gives: 15920401

But the other two logs give an error "ageMinutes" not found etc.

Thanks

Comment: Use `ObjectMapper`!!!

Comment: You can see it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) point 4